# javascript adjust div (show/hide) display according to window scroll bar

Tags: javascript

How to change the div position, i.e in absolute position, up or down according to window scroll position?

If there any information regarding this, please help me out.

Or if there any example over this please share.

Comment: Are you saying that your absolutely positioned div does *not* scroll with the rest of the page when you move the scrollbar, or that it *does* and you don't want it to?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you're saying, but could you be looking for `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`? Fixed position elements don't scroll with the rest of the page, but remain at a specific position in the window.